# Python Flask: Looping through requests and outputting to webpage live

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I want to write a program in Flask that prints out the status codes of websites asynchronously to a webpage with a time delay, i.e.,

```
import flask
import time
import requests
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/yield')
     def index():
          def inner():
              for x in range(100):
                  time.sleep(1)
                  req = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[somenumber]')
                  print(req.status_code)
                  return '<br/>\n' + str(req.status_code)

          return flask.Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')



app.run()
```

The output of this on the webpage is just [image]

when I expected it to be 99 '404' messages due to the for loop's range.

Comment: You can't just stream data to the browser, the way HTTP request works is once the app returns anything it stops execution. To achieve what you want to do you'll need to implement a method for the browser to call periodically back to the server and then add those results dynamically to the website. javascript, jquery, ajax are things to research. plenty of examples on SO to leverage

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement in Flask is what tells the HTTP handler to send the output to the client and close the connection. You do this on the very first iteration of your loop, and so the loop never runs again.

Change to something like this:

```
def inner():
    val = ""
    for x in range(100):
        time.sleep(1)
        req = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[somenumber]')
        print(req.status_code)
        val.append('<br/>\n' + str(req.status_code)) # add to a string
    return val  # and then return the value
```